# Setting a Set to the Contents of a Global Set

Tags: python

I'm making a program in which I use 6 global sets. Inside of various functions that are called I make temporary backup of those sets by doing something like `temp_set = set`. When I do this, the temporary set is somehow modified when I changed the original set. I assume that Python is setting `temp_set` to a pointer to the original `set` here. How can I prevent it from doing this. Rapid response would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use to the [`copy`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) module to create shallow/deep copies.

Even better, use `set.copy()`

Answer (score 2):

Don't use global variables. Instead, give the variables as input to functions. Without more detail there isn't much more to advice.

For now you can do

```
import copy
temp_set = copy.copy(set)
```

However, I would suggest not using them and changing your code so you don't need them (there is a good reference for why not somewhere on stackoverflow, but can't seem to find it. Just take my word for it)

Comment: Is there no way to deal with my current situation?

Comment: @Paul Usually there is no need for `global` as it makes bad code most of the time.